# Saving a list on a java servlet

Tags: java, servlets

In the application I'm building using Java servlets, I have to be able to save a list of objects that contain information about some terminals (phone mobiles) that sent http requests to the servlet. I first thought using a static Vector which I will be creating only once, the first time someone calls the servlet. The problem is, I always find myself in the situation where the Vector object contains only one element, namely the last terminal that called the servlet.
The problem is, I don't even know if this is the way to do it or if there's another approach to it. Can you please make some light?

Thanks!

Comment: Please don't paste any code. It will come to us! Just don't paste, that would ruin the magic.

Comment: would you please add some of the code that you may already worked on. So, we can better help you ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [**Servlet Contex**](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html)

```
ServletContext context = request.getSession().getServletContext();


context.setAttribute("list", listOfval);
```

Comment: So I implemented your method and it works! I don't have time right now to test it thoroughly but I will come tomorrow with a detailed answer. Thanks

Comment: One question: is there ANY reason you used such long way to get `ServletContext` instead of just calling [**`getServletContext()`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/GenericServlet.html#getServletContext()) method, which is available to any class extending `HttpServlet` (that in turn extends [`GenericServlet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/GenericServlet.html) class, in which the above mentioned method declared)?

Comment: @informatik01 TRUE words !! . ultimately storing in context is the idea and there are number of possibilities to get it.So i attached api. :)

Comment: OK, I see your point )